# Why jquery won't let me append an input form FormData.append()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to submit a form and add an extra hidden input, using New FormData.

However everytime I try doing it, it doesn't seem to work. If anyone can help me out with this, I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

```
   var serialized_form =  $("#base-menu-form").serialize(),
      url = "<?=base_url().Backend::$update_menu?>",
       btn = $(this);



    var data = new FormData( this ).append('update_action', whole_menu );
      return false;
```

Comment: Why do you think jquery isn't letting you do it? what are you doing with `data`?

Comment: Show context where this code is called. How can a button be `this` and at same time `this` be a form?

Comment: I am trying to post it using $.post()

Comment: you're probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help guys. I solved the issue by doing the following

```
$.post(url,serialized_form + "&update_action=" + "whole_menu")
```

Comment: urlencode. replace characters that are invalid in a param string with characters that are valid. I'd suggest using `serialized_form + $.param({update_action: whole_menu})` to let jQuery do it for you.

Comment: What is the point of that when all I am doing is passing a string 10 characters?

Comment: If the value never changes, what's the point of the variable in the first place?